# Getting data from textfield in a dynamicallly created table

Tags: php

I have a table which stores user id and username on my php/html page. The data from the table is retrieved from a sql table.

I am working on a page which allows the user to change their username in e table(textfield) the data in the database will be updated when the save button is pressed.

As the number of rows is dynamic i cant hardcode the name of the textfield.

Is there an effient way i can do this?

When the no of row in the table is static  i am doing this to identify the textfield

```
<tr>

  <td><input name="userid1" type="text" size="40" /></td>

  <td><input name="username1" type="text" size="40" /></td>

</tr>
<tr>

  <td><input name="userid2" type="text" size="40" /></td>

  <td><input name="username2" type="text" size="40" /></td>

</tr>
```

Thanks.

Comment: so you update every value in the database on form submit? If not, how do you identify which one changed **in your static example**

Comment: A better way to do this would be to have a separate form for each user, with the id of that users as a form field, so in php you can do (simplified, ignores security for conciseness): `UPDATE users SET username=$_POST['username'] WHERE userid=$_POST['userid']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

First fetch data from table:

`$query=mysql_query("SELECt * FROM table");`

then loop:

`

```
?>
 <table>
 <?php

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
     $userid=$row['userid'];
     $username=$row['username'];
     ?>
     <tr>
          <td><input name="<?php echo $userid; ?>" type="text" size="40" /></td>
          <td><input name="<?php echo $username; ?>" type="text" size="40" /></td>
     </tr>
     <?php
 }
?>
</table>
```

`

I think this will help.

happyCoding :D

Answer (score 0):

you could create a hidden textfield with the total count of textfields, on your php/html site where you display the form:

```
print("<input type = \"hidden\" name = \"numberOfFields\" value = \"".$totalNumber."\" />");
```

or you could save the number in the session:

```
session_start(); //session_start() has to be at the top of the file
$_SESSION["totalNumberOfFields"] = $totalNumber;
```

on your php script where you save the data you can walk through all these fields with an for loop:

```
if(isset($_POST["numberOfFields"]) && is_numeric($_POST["numberOfFields"])) {
    $totalNumber = $_POST["numberOfFields"];

    for($i = 1;$i<=$totalNumber;$i++) {
        if(isset($_POST["userid".$i] && isset($_POST["username".$i])) {
            $userId = $_POST["userid".$i];
            $userName = $_POST["username".$i];
            //handle data...
        }
    }

} else {
    //not set --> error handling
}
```

if you saved the total number of data in the session, you can access it with:

```
$totalNumber = $_SESSION["numberOfFields"]; //make sure you inserted session_start() at the top of the file
```